# Order by association's count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, scope

I have a Country which has many Communities which have many Attractions

```rb
# Country
has_many :communities

# Community
has_many :attractions

# Attraction
belongs_to :community
```

In my `Countries` controller I have this right now:

```
def show
  @communities = @country.communities.all.order('name asc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
end
```

Which gives me the `Communities` ordered by name.

---

How can I order by `Community.attractions.count`, order the community with the most attractions desc.

---

## EDIT

I  changed @muhamad's answer slightly to get to work

```
@communities = Community.joins(:country, :attractions).select("countries.*, communities.*, count(attractions.community_id) as attractions_count").group("communities.id, countries.id").order("attractions_count desc").where("countries.id = ?", @country.id).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

The problem is, every community with 0 attractions is not shown, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use rails `counter_cache`
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

that means you'll have a attractions_count column in `Community` table that would be updated each time an attraction will be added or removed.

```
# Community
has_many :attractions

# Attraction
belongs_to :community, counter_cache: true
```

after that you could easier order communities by `attractions_count` attribute of the community. Something like:

```
@country.communities.order('attractions_count asc')
```

An alternative to counter_cache:
[counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem

Comment: Thanks @rmagnum2002, I didn't want to add a `counter_cache` in the beginning. But I realized how much simpler this solution is for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this query

```
Community
  .select("communities.*, count(attractions.community_id) as attractions_count")
  .joins("LEFT JOIN `attractions` ON attractions.community_id = communities.id")
  .group("communities.id")
  .order("attractions_count desc")
  .where("communities.country_id = ?", @country.id)
```

For this query, you have to join with `attractions` tables only. I was wrong before to join `countries` table whereas you only find communities with country_id in `communities` table and then I find `countries.id` in the where conditions.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Hey Muhamad, thanks for that. I get the error `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "countries.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Try to add `countries.id` in your group.

Comment: I've edited my question, Communities with 0 attractions are not showing up. Do you know why ?

Comment: It means there is a communities that have no attraction. I use full join here so it will not show up. You can change into left join.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have no idea tho how to do that :( (Noobie here). Can you help me out ?

Comment: It's okay. I have updated my query. You can try it. I hope it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91770/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-muhamad-akbar-bin-widayat).

Comment: I suggest you reformat your answer to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling (e.g., break lines on decimal points).

Comment: @CarySwoveland. Thanks for your suggestion. I have done to break lines as long as I can because I don't know how to break lines on decimal point.

Comment: Muhamad, that looks much better. You can either line up the decimal points as you have (my preference) or end each line with a decimal point. Note that IRB sometimes has problems with the former method, but it's valid. I did a small edit, not because I think it's an improvement, but just to show you another option (which is hard to explain in a comment). Go ahead and roll back my edit if you wish.

Comment: @TheMiniJohn try changing `.joins("LEFT JOIN attractions ON attractions.community_id = communities.id")` to `.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN attractions ON attractions.community_id = communities.id")` in order to get communities with 0 attractions.

Comment: @CarySwoveland. It's good improvement. Thank you for you explanation. :)